# PHP - Criar uma lista de checkbox de forma dinâmica

Tags: php, html, mysql

Possuo os seguinte código, onde seleciono categorias de uma tabela MYSQL.

```
<?php
include 'conect.php';
// array que conterá as categorias
$cats = array();



$sql = "SELECT id_carac, nome_carac FROM carac";
$exec = $con->query( $sql ) or exit( $con->error );
$i = 1;
while ( $f = $exec->fetch_object() )
{
    $cats[$i]['id_carac'] = $f->id_carac;
    $cats[$i]['nome_carac'] = $f->nome_carac;
    $i++;
}
foreach ($cats as $key => $value) {
echo "<label><input type='checkbox' name='categoria[]' value='{$value['id_carac']}' > {$value['nome_carac']}</label></br>";
}
?>
```

Desta forma eu consigo exibir o conteúdo selecionado, porém estou com a dificuldade de colocar cada item de forma que gere uma lista de checkbox.

Como exibir essa lista checkbox de forma dinâmica?

Seguindo a resposta do @fernandoandrade o código acima tá funcionando.

Comment: Não use o stacksnippets sem necessidade por favor, leia o help e veja as melhores maneiras de formatar o textos pra situações especificas: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Utilize HEREDOC para gerar dinamicamente a lista.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$cat = [
    ['id' => 1, 'nome' => "Cat A"],
    ['id' => 2, 'nome' => "Cat B"],
    ['id' => 3, 'nome' => "Cat C"],
    ['id' => 4, 'nome' => "Cat D"],
];

foreach ($cat as $key => $value) {
    echo "<label><input type='checkbox' name='categoria[]' value='{$value['id']}' > {$value['nome']}</label>";
}
?>
```

O *name* você deixa como se estivesse declarando um *array*, que no arquivo que recebe o *post* desse seu *form* vai um *array* `$_POST['categoria']`, que são as opções marcadas pelo usuário.

Comment: Amigo obrigado pela atenção... Funfou de voleio ! ;) Vlw

Comment: Por nada, é sempre bom compartilhar conhecimento.

Answer (score 1):

Você poder fazer com que o PHP gere o código HTML através do echo:

```
<?php echo '<input type="checkbox" name="'. $cats[$i]['nome_carac'] . '" value="' . $cats[$i]['nome_carac'] . '">' . $cats[$i]['nome_carac'] . '<br>';
```

Teria que fazer um `foreach` para ir laçando todos os itens de seu array de características.

Comment: Amigo obrigado pela atenção, mas a dúvida é inserir dentro do laço, dei uma atualizada ali mas seguindo essa sua sintaxe tá dando erro, eu tinha feito de uma forma que num dava erro, mas aparecia só o checkbox, sem o valor e só uma vez... Se puder dar uma olhada..

Comment: Eu tinha feito dessa forma-->>echo "<input type='checkbox' name='" . $arrayCats[ $i ]['nome_carac']. "' />\n";<<-- Na linha correspondente, mas só exibe um box sem valor...Apesar que estou vendo exatamente agora que num pus value....kkkk essas horas tmb